# Keep a printer-history for objects with a specific interface in java

Tags: java, oop

I'm making a printer-class where I need to keep track of the print-history of objects with the Employee interface.

```
public void printDocument(String document, Employee employee) {
        System.out.println(document);
        
    }
```

How could I store the history of an employee in a good way, so I can return the print-history of a specific employee with a method like

```
public List<String> getPrintHistory(Employee employee) {
        
    }
```

I have tried storing the print-history of objects in a specific class with the employee interface in a list. The problem is that I want a more general method where I store the information in the Printer class, so I won't have to make a field for print-history for all the classes with the employee interface.

Comment: Try a Map<String, List<String>> having key: employee name for example and value: is list of documents

Comment: You can also make your own `#print` method that would keep this log.